# Jinja: Context as Array

Tags: python, templates, jinja2

Can a Jinja2 context only be a dictionary? In many cases I don't have `{'something': [1, 2, 3]}` but simply `[1, 2, 3]`.

Am I forced to wrap the list into a dictionary in order to loop through it?

**EDIT:** If someone finds it useful, I ended up passing every the context to the following function so that it leaves a dictionary unchanged, but wraps lists in a `{'this': [MY_ARRAY]}` structure.

```
def checked_context(ctx):
    return ctx if isinstance(ctx, dict) else {'this': ctx}
```

Basically, you keep using dictionaries as normal, and can access lists with `this` like in the following example that handles a simple list such as `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
{% for number in this %}
    {{ number }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jinja context is a **namespace**; so yes, you have to use a dictionary, otherwise the values are not bound to names for you to refer to in your template.